# Text analytics API disable in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

Can you help me disable the text analytics api from cognitive services in Azure?
I have created an account and I can’t disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete your text-analytics-api subscription from the Azure Portal.